# Let $P:E\to F$ be a surjective linear map of Banach spaces, that admits a bounded (nonlinear) right inverse. Does $P$ has a linear right inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces, and let $P:E\to F$ be a bounded surjective linear map (imagine $E$ and $F$ to be function spaces, and $P$ to be the restriction map). Suppose there exists some nonlinear function $S:F\to E$ such that $PS=\mathrm{id}_F$, such that $\lVert S f\rVert_E\le C\lVert f\rVert_F$ for all $f\in F$, for some fixed $C>0$. Then can $S$ be modified so as to be linear?

The reason I'm asking this, is because often, when $E$ and $F$ are Sobolev spaces, or spaces of Lipschitz/Hölder-continuous functions, we prove that there exists some bounded extension map, but we don't prove that this map is linear.

Comment: If $T$ is a continuous linear right-inverse of $P$, then $TP$ is a continuous projection on $E$ onto a complement of $\ker P$. Conversely, if $\ker P$ is complemented, we have a continuous linear section. So there is a continuous linear right-inverse if and only if $\ker P$ is complemented.

Comment: By complement of some subspace $A\le E$, do you mean some subspace $B\le E$ such that $E=A\oplus B$?

Comment: Yes if $\oplus$ denotes the direct sum in the category of topological vector spaces. For a Banach space $E$ that means that $A$ and $B$ must be _closed_ linear subspaces of $E$.

Comment: And what precisely do you mean when you say that $TP$ is a projection? Clearly it is idempotent, but do we require anything more?

Comment: To get a decomposition of $E$ as a (topological) direct sum, we also need the linearity and continuity of $TP$. Since we're dealing with general Banach spaces and not necessarily Hilbert spaces, we cannot demand properties like self-adjointness.

Comment: The extension theorems for Sobolev spaces are kind of explicit constructions, which are linear.

Comment: And what about the Lipschitz extension theorem?

Comment: It is a well-known theorem (it is in *Bourbaki* and can also be derived from *Michael's selection theorem*) that every continuous, linear, and surjective map $T:X\to Y$ between Frechet spaces has a continuous right inverse (not necessarily linear). By linear algebra it also has a linear right inverse (not necessarily continuous).